# Is there any java Parser available to parse rabbitmq.conf (erlang) file?

Tags: java, parsing, rabbitmq, erlang, javaparser

I know that in `rabbitmq` latest versions, they have simplified the template of `rabbitmq.conf` file. But for the older versions it has a more complex format, which is more dynamic than structured. I need to read and write those conf files through java.

My conf file is like this:

```
[{rabbit,[

  {ssl_listeners, [5671]}

]}]
```

I would like to know if there is any standard way (e.g. a java parser) available for parsing it, before I proceed writing my own custom parser.

Comment: This might work: https://github.com/metadave/etp (This format is called "Erlang term format", so that's the relevant search term)

Comment: Thank you...the given project working fine.But i am wondering is this project's jar file exist in maven repo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.After some analysis I have found  that the above project's older version like 0.3 and 0.4 are available in maven repo.